# How get member value from xml element

Tags: android, xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/x"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/y"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="x.layout_height*2">
```

Code above doesn't work of course. How can I get height from `x` and e.g multiply this value by 2. Is it possible? Or I should define always some constraint for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
//Java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    EditText x = findViewById(R.id.x);
    EditText y = findViewById(R.id.y);

    y.setHeight(x.getHeight() * 2);
}
```